# Why do (!!) and (.) share precedence 9?

Tags: haskell

New to Haskell, and I hit a simple error on this piece of an expression

```
matches !! length . count
```

> cannot mix '!!' [infixl 9] and '.' [infixr 9] in the same infix expression

This surprised me - why do these operators share a precendence? What prevented Haskell's designers from establishing `(.)` at a higher precendence than `(!!)`?

I can't imagine this was simply overlooked, so I assume there is a rationale here that I am missing.

**Note** I realize that applying `(!!)` to the function that is composed by `(.)` would still result in an error at compile time. I'm curious about why Haskell was designed in a way that allowed for this unexpected error message.

Comment: Why would you expect `.` to have a higher precedence than `!!` and not the other way around?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a rationale to be found behind this specific clash. With "only" ten levels of precedence, some clashes are bound to happen.

Comment: @duplode, the choice of ten precedence levels is frankly bizarre. I'd have expected something more like a partial order under an equivalence relation, allowing operators to be declared as having higher, lower, or equal precedence to arbitrary other operators. But I guess the designers didn't want to wade into the design of a really complex system for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went digging.  There likely is no rhyme or reason for the two infix operators having the same precedence.  In the Haskell 1.0 report, released in 1990, the `(!!)` operator was found in the PreludeList.hs file and the `(.)` operator was in the Prelude.hs file.  Because they deal with completely different things (function composition vs list indexing), and they were in completely different files, it's highly likely that they were not cross coordinated.

Moreover, within the report, these functions in the Prelude were barely mentioned.  `(.)` was just mentioned in a one liner as the composition function and `(!!)` was not mentioned at all outside of the actual source file.

The reason for that ought to be more or less obvious.  The Prelude is useful, but it's not the reason Haskell was developed, and it's not the hard, interesting part of language design.  Haskell was more about lambda calculus and category theory than list indexing.  So it's not surprising that not a lot of thought (or at least not a lot of documentation!) went into exactly what precedence various operators were.

Comment: This provided the catharsis I was looking for, thank you for digging!

Answer (score 8):

Haskell has a lot of operators. Running

```
grep -hor '^infix[lr]\{0,1\} .*$' ghc/libraries/ | sort -u
```

inside my GHC head I get back 137 operators. Not quite all of these are exposed, but still: since precedence has to be between `0` and `9` inclusive, clashes are inevitable.

- `$` should be lower than pretty much everything (fixity 0)
- `>>=` should be higher than `$` (fixity 1)
- `||` should be higher than `>>=` (fixity 2)
- `&&` should be higher than `||` (fixity 3)
- `==` should be higher than `&&` (fixity 4)
- `++` should be higher than `==` (fixity 5)
- `+` should be higher than `++` (fixity 6)
- `*` should be higher than `+` (fixity 7)
- `^` should be higher than `*` (fixity 8)
- `!!` should be higher than `^` (fixity 9)
- `.` should be higher than pretty much everything (fixity 9)

So there isn't really space to differentiate the precedence of `!!` and `.`. Also, I don't think there is much precedent for either `.` or `!!` to be expected to have higher precedence.

Comment: There's no precedent for either to have higher precedence, but it certainly makes much more sense for `!!` to have higher precedence. Neither `(a . b) !! c` nor `a !! (b . c)` has any hope of passing the type checker, but `a . (b !! c)` and `(a !! b) . c` are both potentially valid.

Comment: It's interesting to note, though, that `>>=` would have been a later addition to the hierarchy, and without it there would be room for `.` to have a lower precedence than `!!`. I can't think of much reason why `++` should be higher or lower than `+`, though (assuming the fixity 6 entry should mention `++` instead of `++`).

Comment: @dfeuer, oh, this is interesting.  There might be some principle here.  Operators with specific return types should be lower precedence than those with more general return types, or something like that.

Comment: Yes, @duplode, that's exactly what I was thinking of. I erased my previous confusing comment. I do mean that `a + b : c` can make sense but `a : b + c` cannot, and the former only does when the precedence is right.